# Using ng-content wrapped in ng-template in two places

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-directive

I'm trying to use the ng-template with a ng-content inside in two places. One outside and another inside a mat menu. However when I click on the mat menu, the ng-content outside is no longer being rendered.

[image]

Why is that and how can I fix it?

```
<div>
    <div>
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="actionBtnTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{isMenuView: false}">
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="containerMenu">
        <div class="menu-icon"></div>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #containerMenu>
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="actionBtnTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{isMenuView: true}">
        </ng-template>
    </mat-menu>
</div>

<ng-template #actionBtnTemplate let-isMenuView="isMenuView">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

Also this works fine if it's not ng-content for example hard coding "TEST" works

Comment: I guess by this time you have found a solution? Could you please share it, cos I faced the same problem?

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find a solution ?